# Reading array fields in Spark 2.2

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Suppose you have a bunch of data whose rows look like this:

```
{
    'key': [
        {'key1': 'value11', 'key2': 'value21'},
        {'key1': 'value12', 'key2': 'value22'}
    ]
}
```

I would like to read this into a Spark `Dataset`.  One way to do it is as follows:

```
case class ObjOfLists(k1: List[String], k2: List[String])
case class Data(k: ObjOfLists)
```

Then you can do:

```
sparkSession.read.json(pathToData).select(
    struct($"key.key1" as "k1", $"key.key2" as "k2") as "k"
)
.as[Data]
```

This works fine, but it kind of butchers the data a little bit; after all in the data `'key'` points to a list of objects rather than an object of lists.  In other words, what I really want is:

```
case class Obj(k1: String, k2: String)
case class DataOfList(k: List[Obj])
```

My question: is there some other syntax I can put in `select` which allows the resulting `Dataframe` to be converted to a `Dataset[DataOfList]`?

---

I tried using the same `select` syntax as above, and got:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: need an array field but got `struct<k1:array<string>,k2:array<string>>;`

So I also tried:

```
sparkSession.read.json(pathToData).select(
    array(struct($"key.key1" as "k1", $"key.key2" as "k2")) as "k"
)
.as[DataOfList]
```

This compiles and runs, but the data looks like this:

> DataOfList(List(Obj(org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@bb2a5516,org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@bec5e4a7)))

Any other ideas?

Comment: Of course one workaround is to read the data in and then apply a `map` to beat it into the right form, but this can get a bit clunky - particularly if only one field of many is causing a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just recast data to reflect expected names:

```
case class Obj(k1: String, k2: String)
case class DataOfList(k: Seq[Obj])

val text = Seq("""{
  "key": [
    {"key1": "value11", "key2": "value21"},
    {"key1": "value12", "key2": "value22"}
  ]
}""").toDS

val df = spark.read.json(text)

df
  .select($"key".cast("array<struct<k1:string,k2:string>>").as("k"))
  .as[DataOfList]
  .first
```

```
DataOfList(List(Obj(value11,value21), Obj(value12,value22)))
```

With extraneous objects you define schema on read:

```
val textExtended = Seq("""{
  "key": [
    {"key0": "value01", "key1": "value11", "key2": "value21"},
    {"key1": "value12", "key2": "value22", "key3": "value32"}
  ]
}""").toDS

val schemaSubset = StructType(Seq(StructField("key", ArrayType(StructType(Seq(
  StructField("key1", StringType),
  StructField("key2", StringType))))
)))

val df = spark.read.schema(schemaSubset).json(textExtended)
```

and proceed as before.

Comment: This helps a lot - thank you!  However, I'm unsatisfied: from experimentation  it appears that the string in the call to `cast` must fully specify a schema for the objects in the array in contrast to the normal `select` syntax which allows you to grab only what you want.  Is there a simple modification to your solution which works even if there are `"key3"`, `"key4"`, etc. in these objects (but you only care about `"key1"` and `"key2"`)?  Other than creating a verbose schema for the `cast`?

Comment: OK, this looks like it meets all of my needs - I'm surprised at how verbose the solution is in the end, but in retrospect I guess this sort of runs against the grain of the `Dataframe` API a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: DataFrames aside, I think that some verbosity is unavoidable here, since we require both structure and names mapping over nested structure.  If you use generics for example, you'd have to both input and output structures. If things were flat, it would be much easier `df.select(explode($"key")).select($"col.key1" as "k1", $"col.key2" as "k2").as[Obj]` and if names were matching, even simpler `case class ObjRaw(key1: String, key2: String); df.select(explode($"key")).select($"col.*").as[ObjRaw]`